# Saving each dataframe from a list to separate csv files

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Im trying to save each element from a list to each separate csv files. each element is a dataframe.

I used the following codes, however, the problem is that the files that it saves are only from the first or last element of the list from the two following codes respectively. e.g. the output files are all identical

```
for x in allcity:
    for a in range(0,20):
        x.to_csv('msd{}.csv'.format(a))

for a in range(0,20):
    for x in allcity:
        x.to_csv('msd{}.csv'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the nested loop will write the last data frame from the `allcity` list to the range of values in both cases. You have two options:

```
counter = 0
for x in allcity:
    x.to_csv('msd{}.csv'.format(counter)
    counter += 1
```

or

```
for (counter, x) in enumerate(allcity):
    x.to_csv('msd{}.csv'.format(counter)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, i think you need:

```
for a, x in enumerate(allcity):
        x.to_csv('msd{}.csv'.format(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try f-strings** This is the easiest answer here

```
counter = 0
for x in allcity:
    x.to_csv(f'msd{counter}.csv')
    counter += 1
```